# lubuntu 13.10 giving error code 10 while installation

Tags: lubuntu

I downloaded Lubuntu 13.10 after waiting for the whole night and now on every step its returning with error code 10. Please tell me what to do.

It is saying that installation may fail entirely if I continue.

Comment: please be specific

Answer (score 0):

What you have to do is trying out the installation without internet connection and you will have no problems at all. Once you have it installed apply the updates.

If this is not helping then press F6 when you insert the live CD/USB and chose the option nodmraid.